# Laravel livewire Login resulting in 302 Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I recently added livewire login component on a multi tenant website. Normal laravel login and registration works completely fine but when through livewire i click submit Login page Post request results in 302 found and redirects to a Login route GET request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Livewire\Component;
class Login extends Component
{

    public $email;
    public $password;


    protected $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];



    public function submit(){


        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->email,
            'password' => $this->password
        );
        return $data;
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
        if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else{
            return "error";
        }

    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.login');
    }
}
```

Livewire form

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">

        <input type="email"  class="form-control form-control-lg" wire:model="email">

        @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

        @csrf

        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" wire:model="password">

        @error('password') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror



        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

I have a temporary solution by entering 'livewire/message/login' in VerifyCsrfToken.php

I'm not sure why livewire isn't able to fetch the csrf token from head tag

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

what could be the reason

Comment: A 302 is a redirect response. The CSRF token has nothing to do with login/auth-state, so I cannot see how whitelisting that route from CSRF protection would change anything. If it was a CSRF issue, you would get a 419 - Page Expired response instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `submit()` method returns `$data`, which means no line of code will get executed after return statement.

```
public function submit(){


    $data = array(
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password
    );
    return $data;

    // Below code will never get executed

    $validatedData = $this->validate();
    if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
        return redirect('/');
    } else{
        return "error";
    }

}
```

You are not validating data at all.

Comment: Please check the edited question